# How to change the Language of portlet's title?

Tags: liferay, locale, liferay-6

I am trying to change the language of portlet title, but didn't succeed!
I went through the various link from liferay's forum, but unable to achieve my task.

[Example:1](http://www.opensourceforlife.com/2012/07/portlet-title-internationalization.html)

[Example:2](https://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/14839403)

Details: 
I am using following locales fr_FR and zh_CN,with the following values in the concerned properties file

> javax.portlet.title.1_WAR_microblogsportlet=News
>   javax.portlet.title.1_WAR_microblogsportlet=nouvelles(for fr_FR)
>   javax.portlet.title.1_WAR_microblogsportlet=新聞(for zh_CN)

resource bundle is set in portlet.xml as given:

```
<portlet-name>1</portlet-name>
<display-name>Microblogs</display-name>
<portlet-class>com.liferay.microblogs.microblogs.portlet.MicroblogsPortlet</por‌​tlet-class>
<resource-bundle>content.Language</resource-bundle>
```

Comment: Are you targetting stock Liferay portlets (e.g. "Web Content Display") or your own portlets?

Comment: @OlafKock Thanks for your reply! I am targeting my own Custom portlet.

Comment: Provide more details here like, configuration in your portlet.xml, Your custom Lanugage properties file name and its content and user locale settings.

Comment: @Haris my portlet.xml:
`<portlet-name>1</portlet-name>`
`<display-name>Microblogs</display-name>`
`<portlet-class>com.liferay.microblogs.microblogs.portlet.MicroblogsPortlet</portlet-class>`
`<resource-bundle>content.Language</resource-bundle>`

Comment: my language properties file name is language.proeprties contents are:  `javax.portlet.title.1_WAR_microblogsportlet=News` and in language_fr.properties `javax.portlet.title.1_WAR_microblogsportlet=nouvelles` and in language_zh_CN.properties `javax.portlet.title.1_WAR_microblogsportlet=新聞` locales are fr_FR and zh_CN

Comment: It may be good to edit your question with details than to mention in comment. Do you have <supported-locale> tag in portlet.xml ? Also What language that you are trying to change ?

Comment: @Haris Hello, everything is fine translation is okay in dropdown list of portlet. But after when i add it on page its displaying it in english! whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have property with key as "javax.portlet.title", no need to put your portlet ID as part of key.

Name the localized properties files and put property value as below.

**Language.properties**

> javax.portlet.title=News

**Language_fr.properties**

> javax.portlet.title=nouvelles

**Language_zh.properties**

> javax.portlet.title=新聞

Then liferay displays portlet in corresponding language depending on user's locale.

You may test in one of below ways.

**For User -**

In current user profile -> Display Settings, Select language as French and then visit the page having your portlet. It should display title in french instead of english.

**Change in URL**

You may also specify locale in page URL as described in [liferay 6.1 documentation](https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/localize-your-portlet)

```
http://localhost:8080/fr/<your page url>
```

**Using Language portlet**

Add Language portlet on your page and clicking on French flag changes locale to french and the page should display portlet title in French.